# How to extrude with steps

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I'm doing an extrusion with a bunch of connected edges in the same direction. In order to divide the new faces into several faces along the extrusion direction, I have to do several extrusions.

Is there an option in Blender to determine the number of divisions like in Maya?

[image: Maya extrude options]

Comment: I don't know how to do that in one step, but you could either: 1. do the extrusion to the full length, then select the extruded edges and subdivide those; or 2. repeatedly extrude (once for each segment).

Comment: Subdividing also creates faces along the edge direction, which creates super elongated faces and increasing the face count so I'd rather not do it. Number 2 seems like the only other option but I'm not sure how to keep the length of each segment the same.

Comment: You can control the extrusion length numerically—for example: Select face, [E], [2], [Return] would extrude the face 2 units along its normal vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subdivide the extrusion in a subsequent step using a loop cut.

1. Select the edges to extrude
2. Extrude with <kbd>E</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type `Loop Cut` (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
4. Select the extruded region and set your number of cuts. This setting can be found in the Tool Shelf or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>

[image: extrude and loop cut]

Comment: Please improve the answer if you have an idea. I cannot delete it since it was accepted (and maybe it did provide a solution after all).

Comment: The reason I clicked _Recommend Deletion_ is that this is put in he form of a question, as though you're asking the OP to clarify what he's actually trying to achieve. Instead of asking "Is this what you're trying to achieve", try to explain what it is you're doing. There's nothing with your solution, just with how you presented it. Rephrase it, and it will be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to duplicate the vertices you want to extrude. Move them where you need them, then shift select the original vertices and connect them using [**Bridge Edge Loops**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html?highlight=bridge#bridge-edge-loops)

(to access bridge edge loops press the space bar and type "bridge" or press Ctrl+L and select "Bridge Edge Loops").

You can then enter the **Number of Cuts** you need.

[image]